# NodeJS Multer unable to catch eroor

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

How do I catch the error invoked and return a res status msg? I am unable to catch any error in  userController.uploadFile and if I tried to do a upload(req,res (err) in the routes.post, req is not defined.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, url);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
}).single('file');
let upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: maxSize },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file);
        if (file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype !== 'image/png') {
          return cb(new Error('Only jpeg images allowed'))
        }
    
        cb(null, true)
      }
});

routes.post('/fileupload', upload, userController.uploadFile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can get this to work with a little tweaking. I've made these changes and tested with a few images.

Your user controller will look a little different, but something like this should work.

I've updated to pass any file too large error to the controller, again this will be in the req.uploadError property, so you can handle as you like.

```
const userController = { 
    uploadFile(req, res) {
        if (req.uploadError) {
            res.status(400).send("An error occurred - " + req.uploadError.message);
        } else { 
            res.status(201).send("All good");
        }
    }
}

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, url);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
});

let upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: maxSize },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        console.log(file);
        if (file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/png') {
            cb(new Error('Only jpeg or png images allowed'));
        } else {
            cb(null, true);
        }
    }
}).single('file');

routes.post('/fileupload', (req, res, next) => { 
    upload(req, res, err => {
        req.uploadError = err;
        next();
    })
}, userController.uploadFile);
```

Comment: Thank  you, but how do I catch the error on my userController.uploadFile?  To send a res message to frontend.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for the update. I'll change my answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks! :D Sorry to bother but do you happen to know how should I catch the file size limit error?

Comment: I'll sure take a look and get back to you!

Comment: I've updated the answer to catch the file size limit error!